# Removing the py.exe at the background

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on tkinter project. While double clicking the python file, the py.exe file is visible in the background which doesn't look good. so is there a way to make the py.exe invisible or resize it.Please help me with your ideas. Thank you

[image]

Sample code:

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

class Demo1:
    data = []
    def __init__(self, master):
        
        
        self.master = master
        self.label=tkinter.Label(text="Add IP/Hostname")
        self.label.pack()
        self.t=tkinter.Text(self.master,height=20,width=50)
        self.t.pack()
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.master,height=3,width=10, text="OK"
                                     )
        self.button.pack()

    
def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: did u use pyinstaller? for making an exe

Comment: @CoolCloud, I am talking about the automatic py.exe which is visible while running every .py files. Thank you

Comment: that is weird, there will not by a py.exe normally. Where do u run ur apps, terminal or do u use an IDE

Comment: @CoolCloud, I usually run it in the IDLE(python) it works fine there but i just want to run it by double clicking the .py file itself.. only that makes the py.exe visible.

Comment: oh its not the right way to run any .py file , we dont just run it by double clikcing it. `.py` cause it to open while they are running because the program might write out some text, and the console is the standard way of showing such text - this dates back to the time of MS-DOS, but other systems also use the same kind of thing. More info refer [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20come%20when%20I%20double%20click%20on%20a%20.py%20a%20black%20thing%20flashes%20and%20then%20disappears%3F%20And%20what/where%20exactly%20is%20the%20%27Python%20Interpreter%27%3F)

Comment: @CoolCloud, oh! Thank you. but there should be a way to hide it or resize it.

Comment: actually there is no way to my knowledge, but take a look at [this](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Hide-command-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.py` extension to `.pyw`. That should suppress the console window.

*Note*: the `.pyw` extension should be associated to be opened with `pythonw.exe`. Normally this is done by the Python installer. If not, select `pythonw.exe` the first time you click on a `.pyw` file. That will make the proper association.

Answer (score 0):

Does that work?

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user64.ShowWindow(ctypes.windll.kernel64.GetConsoleWindow(), 6 )
```

Otherwise please post an example code.

Comment: @ lurad101, Thank you for the suggestion. its not working so i have added some sample code.